# Quartz scheduler with jdbc : **job not saved in database**

Tags: java, jdbc, quartz-scheduler

I have used the JDBC job store technique for saving the jobs.

```
My quartz.properties file is here

    ==========================================
     Configure Main Scheduler Properties  
    ===========================================

    org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = ScheduleReport 
    //its having a method scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, simpleTrigger); 

    org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO

    ============================================
     Configure ThreadPool  
    ============================================

    org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
    org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25
    org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5

    ============================================
     Configure JobStore  
    =============================================

    org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

    org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
    org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.oracle.OracleDelegate
    org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = true
    org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

    org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
    org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000

    org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = qzDS
    org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.driver = oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
    org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.URL = jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:abc
    org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.user = system
    org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.password = abc
    org.quartz.dataSource.qzDS.maxConnections = 30
```

Java file implements jobs :

```
public class ScheduleReport implements Job {
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        JobDataMap dataMap = context.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
        exportReportAsType();
    }
}
```

Another java file with a schedule job :

```
JobDetail jobweek = JobBuilder.newJob(ScheduleReport.class)
                        .withIdentity(jobname+"_"+jobid, "week").build();
jobweek.getJobDataMap().put("reportid", reportid);
jobweek.getJobDataMap().put("jobid", jobid);
jobweek.getJobDataMap().put("reportname", reportname);
jobweek.getJobDataMap().put("dateTime", dateTime);
jobweek.getJobDataMap().put("dateTimeType", sdf1.parse(dateTime));

jobweek.getJobDataMap().put("schedulerService",
        schedulerService);

CronTrigger trigger3 = TriggerBuilder
        .newTrigger()
        .withIdentity(jobname+"_"+jobid, "week")
        .startAt(sdf1.parse(dateTime))
        .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule(weekSch))
        .endAt(sdf1.parse(enddateTime)).build();
// scheduler.start();
scheduler.scheduleJob(jobweek, trigger3);
```

This is my configuration but I'm not able to store jobs in DB. When I saw the table in db `QRTZ_LOCKS` & `QRTZ_SCHEDULER_STATE` only contain data and other tables are blank.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm seeing very similar behavior when I try to dynamically schedule a job using this particular mechanism.

Comment: I figured out that my problem was caused by not being inside a transaction at the time I called `scheduleJob`, while I was using `JobStoreCMT` (actually a Spring-specific subclass). (In fact, I had annotated a calling class with `@Transactional`, but there was another annotation on the same class that was preventing the transactional method proxies from being applied.) Once I properly ensured that my code was executing within a transaction, the job was saved correctly.